# STM32 STLINK debug port connection with Olimex

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, debugging, jtag, swd

I'm currently designing the debug port for my [STM32L4R5](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/dm00125306-getting-started-with-stm32l4-series-and-stm32l4-series-hardware-development-stmicroelectronics.pdf) microcontroller. I'm planning to use the [STLINKV2 debugger](https://www.st.com/resource/en/user_manual/dm00026748-stlinkv2-incircuit-debuggerprogrammer-for-stm8-and-stm32-stmicroelectronics.pdf) but it's using a 20 pin JTAG connector which has a big footprint for my PCB. I saw suggestions that I can use the [Olimex 20pin to 10pin connector](https://www.olimex.com/Products/ARM/JTAG/ARM-JTAG-20-10/), but it seems like the Olimex connector didn't connect the TRSTN pin from the debugger to the Olimex. Is the TRSTN pin important?

And is there any example schematic to connect the Olimex board to a JTAG debugger?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

TRST(N) is optional for JTAG (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JTAG).

However, you might choose to use SWD as opposed to JTAG.  SWD is more modern and supported by the STM32L4 and STLINKV2 via that same connector.  See this document (https://documentation-service.arm.com/static/5fce6c49e167456a35b36af1).

Comment: Will the Cortex debug connector and Cortex Debug +ETM connector work with the STLINKV2 debugger?

Comment: Yes, you can put the Cortex Debug Connector on your board and use the Olimex adapter with the STLINKV2.  All the pinouts are published so just double check them.  If the toolchain supports SWD then I would opt for SWD over JTAG (the connector/adapter supports both).  The Cortex Debug +ETM connector is large like the 20-pin connector you're trying to avoid.  I don't know why you want that.  I suppose it would work if you have the an adapter cable that minds the pinouts.

Comment: I doubt whether the STLINKV2 supports the ETM/trace feature so I don't think you'd be gaining any functionality from the Cortex Debug +ETM connector.